# Using toastr in symfony 4.2.9 using webpack and encore

Tags: symfony, toastr, webpack-encore

I'm trying to add the toastr library into my project using Webpack/Encore but i'm unable to make it work.

I'm using Yarn to mange libraries in node_modules/

In my app.js, i have :

```
$(() =>
{
    toastr.info("test");
});
```

And i tried

1. Simple import in app.js just before my code

   ```
   import "toastr";
   ```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

2. Another import i've found while googling my problem

   ```
   import * as toastr from 'toastr';
   import '../../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css';
   ```

> This one work but looks like the CSS isn't : The popup is transparent with just borders

3. Add provide variable in webpack.config.js

   ```
   .autoProvideVariables({
           "window.toastr": require.resolve("toastr")
   })
   ```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

4. Add entry in webpack.config.js

   ```
   .addEntry('toastr', [
       './node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js',
       './node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css'
   ])
   ```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Comment: Did you execute "yarn add toastr" command?

Comment: of course, i made a mistake on the path for the 4th point, i corrected it in my post

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work in this strange way

In webpack.config.js, the CSS :

```
.addEntry('toastr', [
    './node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css'
])
```

In app.js, the import line :

```
import * as toastrlib from 'toastr';
$(() =>
{
    toastrlib.info("test");
});
```

I probably missed something, and want to do it the right way. this one is probably a wrong one even if it is working, so i'm still reading for the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
import toastr from 'toastr/build/toastr.min';
```

at the beginning of app.js file was enough.

I think than when we use `import "toastr"` or `require('toastr')` javascript interpreter treat 'toastr' folder as a toastr file.

So we should be more precise when pointing at file.